# Gulp Sass não funciona

Tags: javascript, sass, gulp

Até agora tudo funcionou no gulp perfeitamente, menos o sass.

Meu Código:

```
var sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');

gulp.task('styles', function(){
    gulp.src('./src/scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/css/'));
})

gulp.task('default', function() { 
    gulp.run('styles');
});
```

O erro que ele me retorna é:
Arguments to path.join must be string

algm sabe o problema? já passaram por isso?

Comment: ahh achei outro plugin gulp sass mais simples que funciona

Comment: "gulp.task('styles', function(){" troque por "gulp.task('sass', function(){" e aqui "gulp.run('styles');" por "gulp.run('sass"');

Comment: creio que não é o nome o problema, ja fiz isso também e não funciona

Comment: Tente usar este https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass ai invés do "gulp-ruby-sass"

Answer (score 2):

Além de teres que incluir:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
```

Tens de usar https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass e não o gulp-ruby-sass. A estrutura de folders é diferente e o interpretador também.

Comment: João explica porquê,  assim a reposta fica mais completa e pode ser mais util a outros também.

Answer (score 1):

Usando o **gulp-ruby-sass** você precisa ter o Ruby instalado no seu computador e o gem do sass devidamente atualizado. Além disso falta adicionar o gulp e o código pra compilar os arquivos é um pouco diferente.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');

gulp.task('styles', function(){
    sass('./src/scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/css/'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['styles']);
```

O **gulp-sass**, que usa o libsass ao invés do Ruby, não precisa de nada instalado no computador e funciona exatamente da forma como você escreveu.